# How do I not show_diff when I do puppet agent -t?

Tags: puppet

puppet agent -t shows diffs of binary files sometimes and it messes up my terminal.  How can I get it to not show diffs at all?

Answer (score 3):

As noted by [Preflightsiren](https://serverfault.com/users/6550/preflightsiren) in this [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/474515/how-do-i-not-show-diff-when-i-do-puppet-agent-t/481558#comment535508_481558):

```
you could replace -t with "--verbose --onetime --ignorecache --no-daemonize"
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  Add `--no-show-diff` and you won't see the diff in the terminal.  `puppet agent --verbose --onetime --no-daemonize --no-show-diff`

Answer (score 2):

> `puppet agent -t` shows diffs of binary files sometimes and it messes
>   up my terminal. How can I get it to not show diffs at all?

I'm afraid that the answer is you can't. Because the `--test` option enable the `show_diff`, even if you add `--no-show_diff` or `show_diff = false` to the command line:

**`puppet help agent`**

```
* --test:
  Enable the most common options used for testing. These are 'onetime',
  'verbose', 'ignorecache', 'no-daemonize', 'no-usecacheonfailure',
  'detailed-exit-codes', 'no-splay', and 'show_diff'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean options are negated by specifying `no-`, so you just want `puppet agent -t --no-show_diff`.

Comment: Doesn't work with Puppet 3.4.3, don't know about newer versions